# How to debug after packaging with electron-packager?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I'm trying to pack my app into a executable. I've done it successfully before, but after doing a
refactor of my code repo it just wont start up after packing.

It runs fine when just using this: `electron dist/main.js`
But when trying to package it, I get **no** errors when packing, but the app won't startup. I can see the process in task manager, but no visual application is seen. How can I go about to debug this as I don't get any errors when building?

The command I use for building:

```
electron-packager dist movie-ex
--out=build 
--platform=win32
--arch=x64 
--icon=dist/icon.ico 
--overwrite
```

Comment: Already tried most of theese. And most include that I need to open devTools, which I can't; because there are no window open to use shortcuts on. I can see the process in taskmanager, but no visual app that's open in the task bar. I am trying the remote debugger now but it doesn't seem to work either as I get "cannot connect".

Comment: Nope. Tried it. Even tried forcing an app crash with `process.crash()`, and the crashreporter wont even log it, even though the crashreporter api is listening for post's.

Comment: OK, applogize for the snarky comments then :-/ - anyway, is it possible you've got a hardcoded path someplace that doesn't work in production? (although it would on your local machine)

Comment: No worries. I've tried to look over all the paths I am using, but you are probably right. It have come to mind that this may be a pathing issue. After doing even more digging, I think i just need to comment out what I can and uncomment then build, repeat until I can find the error. But thanks anyways. Will post the answer as soon as I find it.

Comment: Are you doing anything with dev tools extensions. I seem to recall an issue a while back that made Electron crash silently. Most probably fixed by now, but if you have some odd extensions enabled, I might actual start there. Disable everything that is related to extensions, special GPU usage, etc.

Comment: No extensions via devtools, or the browser window in this case. Just plain and simple, load a html file. The weird part is that after i build into a node app, instead of an executable it works fine with no errors or warning, even in the dev tools window. But when packaged to .exe, just a process in taskmanager is shown. There is no indication other than that that the application is running. Even the RAM usage is weird (8MB only).

Comment: Have you tried `electron-packager .` in the project folder? Is it possible to provide the project? Without a [example] can only guess.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yea, I've tried that too. The whole project can be found here: https://github.com/kaizokupuffball/movie-ex

I have now removed anything regarding both electron-packager and electron-builder though. So you need that in this case if you are to check it out. Tried out electron-forge too, but that is a new learning curve all over again... :')

Comment: A little isolation here: If you're using electron-packager it sounds as if that works fine since you app works in pre-build production mode on your platform. That points to electron-builder as the culprit potentially. Do you agree?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5600

Comment: Oh lord.. Yea, think i found the error... I solved that error described in the issue you posted by adding polyfills to the webpack configuration.. i think if i remove the polyfill configuration again i might be able to package it again. Gonna test it tomorrow. I'll give you an answer then

Comment: fingers crossed!

Comment: Couldn't wait. It worked. Man, thank you for all the help and the time used on this. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: So glad you got it sorted! I guess the answer to your question - "slogging through poor documentation and lots of bug reports!" Take care, have fun -- back on track.